# dbt: Syntax error: Unexpected "%" in generic test

Tags: jinja2, dbt

i followed the document https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/best-practices/writing-custom-generic-tests and was trying to write the generic test "is_even" from here but when i am running the below generic test called is_even using dbt test command,it is giving me the error - "Database Error in test is_even_my_first_dbt_model_id (models/example/schema.yml)
Syntax error: Unexpected "%" at [25:23]"

test_is_even.sql -

```
{% test is_even(model, column_name) %}

with validation as (

    select
        {{ column_name }} as even_field

    from {{ model }}

),

validation_errors as (

    select
        even_field

    from validation
    -- if this is true, then even_field is actually odd!
    where (even_field % 2) = 1

)

select *
from validation_errors

{% endtest %}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this with an example directly in your target db/schema? Is the same error showing up? Also, in which directory do you have `test_is_even.sql`?

Comment: @AleixCC yes, i am referring inside schema.yml like models:
  - name: my_first_dbt_model
    description: "A starter dbt model"
    columns:
      - name: id
        description: "The primary key for this table"
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null
          - is_even

Comment: test_is_even.sql is in tests\generic directory

Comment: error is comin in the line (even_field % 2) = 1 because of %

Comment: Have you tried using the `%` operator in your db before?

Comment: @AleixCC no, i haven't

Comment: try something like `select 2 % 2` and let us know. If it raises an error, then that means that the `%` operator is not usable in your DBMS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251272/discussion-between-tushaar-and-aleix-cc).

Answer (score 0):

The datawarehouse for me was bigquery and to find the remainder, we use MOD function not %